# How integrate signalR in React.js between a scanner Fujitsu and my application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, sdk

How can I integrate SignalR into my ReactJS and NodeJS project for communication between a Fujitsu scanner machine and a web application?
In the SDK documentation, I have the following information.

I want when I put a document in scanner , the application give me the document putted in scanner

You will see the captures below

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.co[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tX9e.png)m/eodiG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXN92.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JSFW.png)

I want when I put a document in scanner , the application give me the document putted in scanner.

You will see the captures below.